# Closed form of geometric recursive function

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, recursion, piecewise-continuity

I was wondering whether there is a universal formula to find the closed form of a recursive compound geometric sequence. With $d$ being the default value, $a$ being the added value each time, and $n$ being the exponent raised.

$$ f(x)= \begin{cases}
x=1:d \\ x>1:(a+f(x-1))^n
   \end{cases}
$$
For example, if $x=3$, $n=\frac{1}{2}$, $a=2$, and $d=\phi$, we get
$$ \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\phi}}$$
Every time $x$ increases, we add a square root.
$$x=4:\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\phi}}} \\ x=5:\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\phi}}}} \\ \cdots$$

Comment: It's hard to follow you, in particular for exponent $n$... Could you give us the usual direct formula ? Is it $f_{k+1}=af(k)+b$ or something like that (arithetico-geometric sequence) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie It's like that, but with an added exponent, like $$f(k+1) = (af(k)+b)^n$$.